# pylatex: is it possible to only create LaTeX fragments, not complete documents?

Tags: python, pylatex

I would like to use pylatex to create only fragments of LaTeX (i.e., give a nice math-style format to a numpy array) for inclusion into another doc (i.e., Jupyter notebook).

It is easy to embed LaTeX into Jupyter output cells using the `IPython.core.display.Latex` display processor [as in `IPython.display.Latex('Some LaTeX')`]. I then can convert the notebook to LaTeX using my converter at https://github.com/NelisW/ipynb2tex, which can extract the LaTeX code from the mime type 'text/latex' object embedded in the output cell.

All the examples in the pylatex docs create full LaTeX documents including the class definition, `\begin{document}`, etc.  If we can extract only smaller sections of latex code generated by pylatex, we can use such fragments inside the Jupyter notebook for later LaTeX typesetting.

Hence my question: is it possible to 'calculate' only small sections of LaTeX code with pylatex, instead of the full document?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. See the Library Usage page in the documentation:
https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/usage.html#the-classes

> Classes can be part of a single document, or can act as pieces on their own. With the `dumps` method, most classes can return their LaTeX-formatted code, and with the `generate_tex` method, this code can be written to a file.